# Buildozer failed to Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy, buildozer

I am new to kivy and buildozer. I have been trying to start off by trying to debug and deploy a sample code on my phone. But I have been getting this error consistently.I have checked and found the zip files in the directory. Please help, this is the error below:

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
            "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
            exec code in run_globals
          File "/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
            main()
          File "/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
            ToolchainCL()
          File "/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
            getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
          File "/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
            build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
          File "/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
            build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
          File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 559, in build_recipes
          File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 520, in prepare_build_dir
          File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 405, in unpack
          File "/home/shugas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1245, in __call__
            return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
          File "/home/shugas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 633, in __init__
            self.wait()
          File "/home/shugas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
            self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
          File "/home/shugas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
            raise exc
        sh.ErrorReturnCode_9: 

          RAN: /usr/bin/unzip /home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius/master.zip

          STDOUT:
        Archive:  /home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius/master.zip


          STDERR:
          End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
          a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
          latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
          the last disk(s) of this archive.
        unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius/master.zip or
                /home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius/master.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius/master.zip.ZIP, period.

        # Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=gps --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,plyer,pyjnius --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/shugas/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build
        # 
        # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
        # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
        # Please read the full log, and search for it before
        # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
        # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```